# Modeling a circular shape with round extrusions along the edge

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm making this pocket watch and am wondering how to make this design where there are a lot of round extrusions. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The answer will depend upon how you plan to use the result. For example, in a game, you might make a simple mesh and use as image texture to provide some of the smaller details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In top view add a curve. Enter Edit mode and shape it to something like this:

[image]

Still in Edit mode Select All (<kbd>A</kbd>) and Rotate it 90 degrees in X (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>)and 90 degrees in Z (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>)

[image]

Exit edit mode and add a Curve->Circle

[image]

Select your original curve, make it 3D, check on Fill->Full and give it some extrusion.

[image]

Add an Array modifier. Select fit curve and select the circle.

[image]

Add a Curve modifier and select the circle again.

[image]

Edit the curve, extrusion, radius and offset to meet your needs.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Start with a mesh->circle with a lot of vertices.

[image]

Estrude and Scale:

[image]

With all of the edges/faces selected Press <kbd>I</kbd> to activate the **Inset** Tool and enable **Indivdual**.

By controling thethickness and depth you should be able to get something like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Smooth and subsurf:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a mesh circle and make it so it has a lot of segments (make it an even number though) In this example I chose 120

[image]

By extruding and adding loop cuts create a shape like this:

[image]

Select an edge like this and then do Select->Similar->Lenght

[image]

Now do Select->Checker Deselect. So you end up with every other edge selected.

[image]

[image]

move those edges up on the Z axis.

[image]

Smooth and subsurf:

[image]