# Creating a single vertex on the cursor position

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

How do I create a single vertex (not connected to another vertex) on the cursor position?

Comment: Changed the question. Is it still a duplicate?

Comment: I typically add something like a plane then use *Alt M* > merge at center. Perhaps that's too much of a workaround..

Comment: For a simple vertex, that's indeed a serious workaround. Alternatively, I could create a vertex (ctrl+LMB), position the cursor where a want it, select the vertex, execute "selection to cursor" and voilà, but that's a hassle as well.

Answer (score 18):

If you press the left mouse button while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> you can add vertices at will. Any subsequent vertices created will be connected by an edge.

[image]

To create unconnected vertices only you would need to deselect the previous vertex.

[image]

Comment: The question has changed to creating a vertex at the cursor position. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not working for me.

Comment: @prolink007 Just tried it on version 2.79b and it works fine. What version of Blender are you running?

Comment: As of Blender 2.80 : Ctrl + RMB  is used instead.

Comment: @TavernSenses Why not just use Snap Selection to Cursor after creating the vertex?

Answer (score 18):

The "extra objects" addon (included in the latest release of blender) has a add object> single vertex option. See the second half of [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36675/how-to-model-a-ridged-dial-or-gear-shape?answertab=active#tab-top) to learn how to enable the addon. the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>>**Single Vertex**.

Comment: I don't want really want to create an extra object, just a vertex.

Comment: well, if you do it in edit mode it will make only one vertex at the cursor position

Comment: Couldn't find the add-on (have version 2.76)

Answer (score 5):

To expand on @cegaton's answer:

After creating a vertex with Ctrl+Left Mouse, you can use Shift+S > "Selection to Cursor" to move the vertex to the 3D cursor's position.

If you want to move several vertices to the cursor position but keep their relative shape, use Shift+S > "Selection to Cursor (Offset)"