# How do you add single free floating vertices as primitives at a given XYZ coordinate postion

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices

I am sure this question has been asked before but I have searched and searched and I can't find it (I even vaguely remember asking it in 2013 5 years ago).

I am easily fooled by perspective illusions, and prefer to plot rather than to sculpt, in 3D, because of this.

Is there a way I can make single vertices a primitive in the primitives menu, like that darn monkey (long live suzie), so that I can place a bunch of points in a row with minimum effort, and then connect them and create edges and faces at the end?

I vaguely remember reading about a potential plug-in solution, but that was quiet a while ago, and I can't find my source, so I'm totally lost

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts are pain in the wrists man

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43097/599

Comment: Maybe, I just saw your response, Imma click it now get I'll back to you shortly

Comment: If you want to avoid all the other stuff which comes with the extra objects addon, you could also try making your own single vertex primitive: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8275/599

Comment: No. I don't want it on the cursor position, I want a box where I can type in 3 coordinates and press enter to create vertex there, and then it clears and lets me start typing another point. So that I can create a whole bunch in one go.

Comment: Umm I instinctively format my text and hit 'enter' early, so that comment was not ready for being shared, too late now, I'm kicking myself

Comment: I was gonna ask if (cos my memory of primitives is still from 2013 and might be faulty) there was anything like that; or if there was a path I could take to code it myself? I don't know python, but I can soldier through if I have lots of reference material, I guess.               ----- I do have C++ experience and am good at following tutorials

Comment: hehe, you can still edit for something like 3 minutes, go! (also shift+enter lets you put newlines in,  
 but they won't be rendered)

Comment: (Response: Yeah, but sometimes I spend a bit typing, plus I was half finished anyways so bfd in the grand scheme, just "-whoops-" is all I meant by it)

Comment: This link you shared might be exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much! " blender.stackexchange.com/a/43097/599 " but the mass production point plotting box still sounds fun... ...... ...hmm...

Comment: I don't know if any existing way to get a textbox based workflow like that, no. But it definitely sounds possible to implement with an addon. If you are familiar with coding at all it should be very doable. There are some useful example scripts accessible in *Templates > Python* in the text editor.

Comment: Also, [this addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/60682/599), especially bit about creating a property dialog, may be a useful example. And of course, feel free to ask a new question for any addon-implementing questions you run into :)

Answer (score 1):

It was the [Extra Objects addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43097/599).

I was going to use it to create a point primitive, so I misrembered it and used the wrong keyterms while searching for it.

I did have a neat/convenient idea while trying to figure this one out, I'm not sure if that's a seperate question or just an alternate solution though (about the point plotting box).

So if something like that exists [the enmasse point plotting box], feel free to comment it to me, if it doesn't then I guess I'll have to ask/or/find some more questions later [about making plugins, and creating a tiny little app/menu for that in blender]